# World Map without latitude and longitude

Tags: r, ggplot2, rworldmap

I have a data frame:

```
| Country       | Country_code | Id   | Unique_person |
|---------------|--------------|------|---------------|
| India         | IN           | 40   | 2             |
| China         | CN           | 3781 | 1             |
| Mexico        | MX           | 40   | 1             |
| United States | US           | 1000 | 14            |
| United States | US           | 3781 | 566           |
| United States | US           | 40   | 43            |
| United States | US           | 65   | 908           |
| United States | US           | 815  | 78            |
```

I need to plot world map using ggplot2 such that the size of 'unique_person' varies based on different color coded 'Id' in each country. Since I do not have latitude and longitude, I'm unable to plot the world map. Can someone please help me with this problem?

Answer (score 1):

Although I may not understand correctly the Id issue, you can plot the map without using  latitude and longitude as below. I hope this helps you.

```
library(rworldmap)
dat<-data.frame("country"=c("India", "China", "Mexico", "United States"), "Unique_person"=c(2, 1, 1, 14))
sdat <- joinCountryData2Map(dat, joinCode="NAME", nameJoinColumn="country")
mapCountryData(sdat, nameColumnToPlot="Unique_person", catMethod="fixedWidth", addLegend = TRUE)
```

[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vbkvN.png)

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple ways of plotting geographical datas, one good and simple start is to use `ggplot2` combined with the `maps` package that provide geographical polygons mapping the world countries.

You can use the `world` map dataset and merge it with your data, for example based on the country names, to obtain geographical coordinates. I have not fully understood what you want to plot, but the base case for you could be:

## Data

```r
structure(list(Country = c("India", "China", "Mexico", "United States", 
"United States", "United States", "United States", "United States"
), Country_code = c("IN", "CN", "MX", "US", "US", "US", "US", 
"US"), Id = c(40, 3781, 40, 1000, 3781, 40, 65, 815), Unique_person = c(2, 
1, 1, 14, 566, 43, 908, 78)), class = c("spec_tbl_df", "tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -8L), spec = structure(list(
    cols = list(Country = structure(list(), class = c("collector_character", 
    "collector")), Country_code = structure(list(), class = c("collector_character", 
    "collector")), Id = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double", 
    "collector")), Unique_person = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double", 
    "collector"))), default = structure(list(), class = c("collector_guess", 
    "collector")), skip = 1), class = "col_spec"))
```

## Code

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(maps)

data$Country[data$Country == 'United States'] <- "USA" # names are different for USA in datasets

data <- merge(data, 
              map_data("world"), by.x = "Country", by.y = "region") %>%
  arrange(Country, order)

ggplot() + 
  # world map
  geom_polygon(data = map_data("world"), 
               aes(x=long, y = lat, group = group),
               fill = "grey50") +
  # custom map
  geom_polygon(data = data,
               aes(x=long, y = lat, group = group, fill = Id))
```

Comment: I'm sorry for not being clear with my question. What I want to do is to create bubble plots on world map such that 'Id' represents the bubble and size of bubble is determined by the value of 'unique_person'. For example, there will be 8 bubbles of 4 colors belonging to unique country names. Also, the value of 'unique_person' is highest for China and one of the records for USA. So, the size of bubbles for these will be largest, followed by other values in descending order.